# Message not flashing in cakephp edit function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Simple question for some I am sure.  The function itself is doing what is asked, but the message is not being flashed when actioned.

Function below:

```
function edit($id = null) {
            if($this->Auth->user('id')==$id) {
                $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to edit other member profiles', true));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Member profile saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Member profile could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }
        $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('groups'));
    }
```

Still learning the cakephp ropes and kindling some very old PhP skills - so bear with me!  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `echo $this->Session->flash();` in your layout (or view)?

Comment: @mattb echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); sitting in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another line underneath

```
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

Like this:

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

This will show regular flash messages

passing 'auth' to the flash method will only show auth flash messages and nothing else. See http://api13.cakephp.org/class/session-helper#method-SessionHelperflash for more information.

Comment: I can't believe it was something as simple as that - I was near pulling the hair out mucking around with the controller..  Many thanks!!

Comment: Any time, glad I could help :-)